# Glide gradle and firebaseUI fail to sync

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I am using glide and firebase to manage my upload and download image to show a user profile pic, i follow the github repo where it talks about the firebaseUI and the glide, at the begin when my project worked fine my app gradle was like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

after reading the docs where it says that if i want to include the firebaseUI version i need to upgrade all the compiles related to firebase to 10.2.0, i did this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

but i keep getting a error on my first compile:          `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'`

the error is the following:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.2.0, 25.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.
```

**my project gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        }
    }


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

need some help here im confused about this error :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, this is not relevant with **Glide** library.

gradle says "this project has different versions of android support packages", so you must use all com.android.support packages with same version. for example your project has '25.2.0' and '25.1.1'.

How can I achieve this ? Put this block to app level build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.2.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

you can say "But I just compile my all android support packages with same level which is 25.2.0". some libraries includes android support packages and 25.1.1 is coming from your dependency.

Comment: awesome, can i make another question related to gradle a simple one?

Comment: how can i check if the storage is null on the firebase with glide, i mean glide not gradle xD